# Select tags not working

Tags: php, html, json, forms, select

I was recently working on a website, where it is imperative that I'm able to create options within a select tag dynamically using PHP.  Across all major browsers, when I click on the select form, it shows a slight clicking animation, but won't open the menu.  A live example can be found at https://wilsonandsonproductions.com/buy.php?id=0&mode=client.  PHP does seem to create the correct tags, so I'm not sure where I made my mistake.  Here's some of the source code:

```
<select name="opt" id="opt">
  <label>Select a  size:</label>
  <optgroup label="Metal Print with Wall Mount">
    <!-- Metal prints in form 0e1, w/ 0 as id & 1 as selected option -->
    <?php foreach($pdata["metal"] as $opt){$o=array_search($opt,$pdata["metal"]); echo '<option value="e'.$o.'">'.$opt["label"].' ($'.$opt["price"].')</option>';} ?>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Traditional Matted Print">
    <!-- Traditionl Matted prints in form 0a1, w/ 0 as id & 1 as selected option -->
    <?php foreach($pdata["matted"] as $opt){$o=array_search($opt,$pdata["metal"]); echo '<option value="a'.$o.'">'.$opt["label"].' ($'.$opt["price"].')</option>';} ?>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

The variable $pdata is loaded from a json file, included here:

```
{
"metal" : [
    {
        "label" : "8x10",
        "price" : 75
    },
    {
        "label" : "8x12",
        "price" : 85
    },
    {
        "label" : "8.5x11",
        "price" : 95
    },
    {
        "label" : "10x14",
        "price" : 115
    }
],
"matted" : [
    {
        "label" : "5x7 print inside 8x10 mat",
        "price" : 50
    }
]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have some form of click/keyboard press stopper going on in the background?

Comment: It looks like the select works when you can actually click on it, your blocking the clicks for the whole page though, Also for anyone who really wants those photos, that is not going to stop them....

Comment: @LeoWilson can you include the code you're using to the block clicks on the page?

Comment: You have `document.onmousedown = rtclickcheck;` and then `function rtclickcheck(keyp){ keyp.preventDefault();`. So you are preventing users to click on your page. That's why the `<select>` does not open when you try to click on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you updated the HTML to contain *optgroup* tags with *label* attributes instead of *label* tags. That is good because a select tag can only contain *option* and *optgroup* tags.

> **Permitted content:**  Zero or more [<option>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) or [<optgroup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) elements. <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)</sup>

Your javascript click handler is stopping the default behavior of all clicks (both on the left and right button ), because it has a call to [*preventDefault()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in the first line.

```
function rtclickcheck(keyp){ 
    keyp.preventDefault();
```

That is fine to call, except when used for all mouse clicks. You can use the [*oncontextmenu*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oncontextmenu) event handler instead of *onmousedown*. So this line:

```
document.onmousedown = rtclickcheck;
```

can be changed to:

```
window.oncontextmenu  = rtclickcheck;
```

If there is no need to support IE 8 or earlier version, this technique with [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) can be used, which is more like the [event delegation](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) pattern:

```
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', rtclickcheck, false);
```

You can see it in action in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aelliott/x2ts2443/).